# ICollectionView y DataGridCheckBoxColumn en WPF con MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm

Buen día, estoy trabajando en WPF, tengo el requisito, de hacer una simple tabla, que tenga un filtro sencillo, y a su vez, tenga una columna con `CheckBox` que permita seleccionar múltiples elementos, para luego con un botón realizar ciertas acciones.

Sabiendo esto, por el tema del filtrado, intente implementarlo con `ICollectionView`, pero en este caso, al intentar chequear los `CheckBox`, se dispara la siguiente excepción:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se permite 'EditItem' para esta
>   vista.'

Al ver esto, intente encararlo sin un `ICollectionView` y realizar el bindeo directo a una `ObservableCollection<T>`, pero en este caso se me presenta el problema de no poder filtrarla en tiempo de ejecución.

El bindeo lo hago de esta manera:

```
    <DataGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Catalogos, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsReadOnly="False"
        >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Marca" Binding="{Binding Path=Marca}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modelo" Binding="{Binding Path=Modelo}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Debe Exportarse?" Binding="{Binding Path=EsCatalogo}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

¿Puedo lograr de alguna manera, ya sea, permitir chequear la celda con un `ICollectionView`, o filtrar una `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que la tabla tienes que filstrarla y además poder usar un checkbox en una de sus columnas, son 2 cosas separadas?

Comment: @Leodev Exactamente, la idea es que la tabla se pueda filtrar, pero además, sea posible tildar las filas de alguna manera

Answer (score 0):

Primero te ayudaré con lo del filtro y al final lo otro.

Esto del filtrado siempre lo hago con un `TextBox` y que al escribir en él se busquen en las propiedades de todos los objetos contenidos en la colección y cuyo valor coincida con lo que he tipeado.. para lograr esto puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Primero empecemos por la duda del `ICollectionView`: Acá lo que puedes hacer es declarar tu `ObservableCollection<T>` y debajo una `ICollectionView`, yo siempre convierto la declaración de las `ObservableCollection<T>` a una lista personalizada, en este caso sería algo así aunque es opcional:

```
public class Catalogos : ObservableCollection<Catalogo>
{

}
```

Ahora puedes trabajar con Catalogos en vez de ObservableCollection

```
private Catalogos _listaCatalogos = new Catalogos();
public Catalogos ListaCatalogos
{
    get { return _listaCatalogos; }
    set
    {
        _listaCatalogos = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ListaCatalogos");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ListaCatalogosView");
    }
}
```

(RaisePropertyChanged es mi implementación de INotifyPropiertyChanged, puedes cambiarla por la tuya)

Ahora, luego de eso declaras la ICollectionView

```
public ICollectionView ListaCatalogosView
{
    get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListaCatalogos); }
}
```

Ahora si al filtro, creas tu `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Filtro, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Luego en el ViewModel la propiedad para bindear el Textbox

```
public string Filtro
{
    get { return _filtro; }
    set 
    { 
        _filtro = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Filtro");

        ListaCatalogos.Filter =
        (c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? true : (
        ((Catalogo)c).Propiedad1.ToString().Contains(value) ||
        ((Solped)c).Propiedad2.Contains(value) ||
        ((Solped)c).Propiedad3.Contains(value)  ||
        ((Solped)c).Propiedad3.Contains(value)
        ));

        ListaCatalogos.Refresh();
        RaisePropertyChanged("ListaCatalogos");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ListaCatalogosView");
    }
}
```

Con esto cada vez que escribas algo en el `Textbox` de filtrado se actualizada el `ICollectionView` y éste a su vez actualizará lo que muestra en pantalla, puedes agregar al `Contains` y a `value` un `ToLower` o `ToUpper` para que las mayúsculas y minúsculas no te fastidien.

El `DataGrid` lo bindeas a la colección, no al `ICollectionView`.

```
<DataGridItemsSource="{Binding ListaCatalogos}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCtalogo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Con eso el filtrado no debería ser un problema.

---

Puede ocurrir que por alguna razón al filtrar no pase nada aún cuando esté bien declarado todo, para esto puedes cambiar el comportamiento del filtrado haciéndolo con un `ICommand` suponiendo que tienes implementado esto.

Por ejemplo, si la propiedad `Filtro` no lo hace puedes en vez de hacer que `ICommand` lo haga tomando a `Filtro` como referencia, así:

Y lo bindeas a una propiedad `String` común llamada `Filtro`

```
private string _filtro = string.Empty;
public string Filtro
{
    get { return _filtro; }
    set
    {
        _filtro = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Filtro");

        RaisePropertyChanged("ListaCatalogosView");

    }
}
```

Y finalmente el `ICommand`:

```
private ICommand _filtrarCatalogosCommand;
public ICommand FiltrarCatalogosCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_filtrarCatalogosCommand== null)
        _filtrarCatalogosCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(FiltrarCatalogos));
        return _filtrarCatalogosCommand;
    }
}
```

y su respectivo método de acción:

```
private void FiltrarCatalogos()
{
    try
    {
        ListaCatalogosView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListaCatalogos);

        ListaCatalogosView.Filter = c => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Filtro) ? true : (
        ((Catalogo)c).Propiedad1.ToString().ContainsIgnoreCase(Filtro) ||
        ((Catalogo)c).Propiedad2.ContainsIgnoreCase(Filtro) ||
        ((Catalogo)c).Propiedad3.ContainsIgnoreCase(Filtro)
        );

        ListaCatalogosView.Refresh();
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Y listo.. 2 formas de filtrar, aunque se puede hacer de otras más.

---

Sobre lo del `CheckBox` bindéalo directo a la propiedad del objeto, tal como lo muestras, pero recuerda aplicarle **SIEMPRE** la implementación de `INotifyPropertyChanged` a las listas y objetos que están contenidos en las listas y si, también a las propiedades de esos objetos, no basta con solo aplicarlo a la lista, debes seguir todo el flujo de datos hasta su origen y siempre con `Mode=TwoWay` si es necesario.